# vsCode dependencies bug with nestJs

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, nestjs, npm-install

my vsCode bug to recognize dependencies when i program with nestJs, after setting up the project with: nest new projectname

then after running for example:
npm install --save @nestjs/typeorm typeorm@0.2

vsCode doesn't recognize import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm'; as long as I don't restart the ide.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Typescript Language Server extension isn't updating after adding new directories to the `node_modules`. Instead of fully restarting the IDE you can just restart the Typescript Language Server. `ctrl/cmd + shift + p > Typescript: Restart TS Server`. It'll take less time than restarting the IDE and should get everything updated.

For debugging, you might want to look in the integrated console on the `Output` tab and choose `Typescript` from the drop down, see if it's trying to update and is slow or something else is happening all together.

Comment: I think everything is normal in the output                                                                                  `nfo  - 19:01:22.488] Starting TS Server
[Info  - 19:01:22.488] Using tsserver from: c:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js
[Info  - 19:01:22.489] <syntax> Forking...
[Info  - 19:01:22.499] <syntax> Starting...
[Info  - 19:01:22.499] <semantic> Forking...
[Info  - 19:01:22.512] <semantic> Starting...

Comment: nothing happens after install dependency,  I have to restart manually as you explained to me, so that it detects the dependencies